# fleetctl - How do I update a unit file in the registry?

Tags: coreos

On CoreOS 899.15.0, how do I update a previously submitted unit file via fleetctl?

I've previously submitted the unit file rethinkdb@.service, but want to update it to a revised version:

```
$ fleetctl list-unit-files
UNIT                HASH    DSTATE      STATE       TARGET
rethinkdb-discovery@.service    76b05ae inactive    inactive    -
rethinkdb@.service              faa7a16 inactive    inactive    -
```

When I try to re-submit rethinkdb@.service, fleetctl only warns me that the local and registry versions of it differ:

```
$ fleetctl submit rethinkdb\@.service
WARNING: Unit rethinkdb@.service in registry differs from local unit file rethinkdb@.service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the solution is to destroy the unit files and then re-submit them.

```
fleetctl destroy rethinkdb\@.service
fleetctl submit rethinkdb\@.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming up in fleet version [v0.13](https://github.com/coreos/fleet/pull/1509) (not yet released, August 2016):

Support to replace units

```
fleetctl start --replace rethinkdb\@.service
```